# How to get WebView Content Size

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am looking to find WebView content size to scale data to fit into small size of WebView Frame.

WebView is continuous loading data as getting images from IP Camera so -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method is not called, otherwise [webview sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero] would give receiver content size.

How to get WebView content size which is continuous loading data ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview/3937599#3937599) to a similar question. Instead of `-webViewDidFinishLoad` you should consider calling this using a timer (and checking whether something has been loaded, first).

If the HTML is under your control, you might wanna call it using a JavaScipt `onLoad` handler that tries to fetch a custom URL that you can intercept in `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`.