# screenshot uiwebview content

Tags: iphone, image, uiwebview

I want to do a screenshot of a UIWebView, I use this code

Code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.vistaWeb.bounds.size);
[vistaWeb.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage,nil,NULL,NULL);
```

and it work well, my problem is that I want to make a screenshot of all the uiwebview, not only the visible view...for example, I have a uiwebview of 200x200 but the page is 200x500, whit this code I make a screenshot of 200x200 while I want to do a screenshot of 200x500.what I have to do?

kikko088

Comment: @kikko088: hi i too m facing the same problem..can you share your code?Please help ASAP.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.vistaWeb.bounds.size);
```

You are using the size of your view and not the size of its content. In order to obtain the size of your page use the following [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview). Then just replace `self.vistaWeb.bounds.size` with an appropriate size.

In order to support retina you should replace the first line of your code with the following:

```
CGSize layerSize = ...
if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0f) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layerSize, NO, 2.0f);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layerSize);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!now is perfect....only another question, how can I improve the image quality?now is low-low quality..

Comment: @kikko088 the image will be exactly as on the screen. The only problem I can think of is that your code is not adapted to retina devices. Here is the proper way to begin an image context for all devices: http://codinggeek.org/2011/02/21/retina-and-ios-sdk-part-ii-uigraphicsbeginimagecontext/

Comment: Here I put 3 screenshot, and photo of the camera roll, the webview is ready to retina display, all image are in svg (then are vectorial image)  www.endurodoc.net/1.png www.endurodoc.net/2.png www.endurodoc.net/3.png

Comment: I try it but the quality is the same...I solved in another way, I create a pdf instead an image... :)