# UIWebView Inside UIScrollView Content Size

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have to add `UIWebView` and some buttons and labels inside `UIScrollView`. I have seen many question on how to add `UIWebView` inside `UIScrollView` but unfortunately they were unable to help me complete my task. So kindly don't mark it as duplicate or something.

Theoretically, the problem can be solved by following steps:

1) Make `UIWebView` a subview of `UIScrollView`.

2) Call `setScrollEnabled:NO` for `UIWebView` to disable its native scrolling.

3) Set the content size of both `UIScrollView` and `UIWebView` to the size of the HTML string loaded inside `UIWebview`.

I am using iOS 6 and StoryBoards. I have added `UIWebView` as the subview of `UIScrollView`.

Then in my `webViewDidFinishLoad`, I have used the following:

```
 NSString *webHeight = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height;"];
 NSLog(@"WebView Height %@", webHeight);
```

That gives me the height of the WebView.

On the StackOverFlow, I have come across the following.

```
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    webView.frame = frame;

    NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);
```

Then i have set the size of the `UISCrollView` to the size `UIWebView`:

```
mainScrollView.contentSize = webView.bounds.size;
```

I can scroll down to the bottom but there is a white space at the bottom and `UIWebView` is not making its size according to the size of the loaded html content.

[image]

Looks like `UIScrollView` has changed it size to the size of the content of `UIWebView` but `UIWebView` is not showing all of it. How can I solve this issue?

Kindly do not advice me about the Apple documentation that says you should not use `UIWebView` inside `UIScrollView`. I already know that but I want to use it as per my project requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can shed some light here. I think you are confusing the frame size and the content size. First I'll describe methodology, then make concrete suggestions.

**Methodology**

You have a webView and you correctly disabled the scrolling on it and set the contentSize to the full size of the web content. You should also set the frame size to the full size of the web content. Then you addSubview this to the scrollView at origin (0,0). Set the scrollView contentSize to the full size of the web content. Set the scrollView frame to the bounds of the viewController.view.

**Concrete Suggestions**

- The "fittingSize" code you posted does not look right to me. The purpose of that code is to set the frame of the webView. Use NSLog or breakpoints to find out if that is setting the full size of the web content.
- Note that the purpose of the javascript code that you posted is the same as the "fittingSize" code that you posted. Check to see which one produces the correct output.
- Try to figure out the frame sizes of the webView and scrollView to help you debug. The best way to do that is to set different background colors like this: `setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]`
- My best guess is that the `webView.frame.size` is not being set large enough.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve found same situation that webView do not reflects frame size changing, a blank remains while scrolls down as Jessica mentioned. I checked my project and found I’ve enabled autoLayout feature, so solutions I’ve found are:

1. disable autoLayout.
2. add height constraint to webView, after changing webView frame size,using follow code like:

   self.webViewHeightConstraint.constant = fittingSize.height;
   [webView updateConstraints];

Comment: I have same problem as Jessica and I use autoLayout. You help me with change height constraints. It helps fix this problem. Don't need to disable autoLayout.

Answer (score 0):

To get the height of a UIWebView's **content**, I highly recommend the answer by 'Phenomena' here: [http://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview)
(Not the accepted answer, the one below.)
He/she suggests NOT using 'CGSizeZero', and gives a better solution.