# Load UIImage form NSData in UIWebView and center it

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uiimage

So I basically get an `NSData` of `UIImage` and I use a `UIWebView` to display it. I do it that way:

```
[self.view addSubview:webView];

webView.delegate = self;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

I then load the picture into it like this:

```
NSData *image02Data = attachmentToLoad.attachment_data;
[webView loadData:image02Data MIMEType:@"image/jpg" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

And I get a result that isn't exactly what I want:

[image]

As you can see the image leaves a white bottom line down at the bottom of the `UIWebView`. How can I make the size of the `UIWebView` to be equal to that of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this post? 
[Click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview)

I think it is exactly you want