# Calculate height based on content in webview iOS7

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios7

Actually we are using a webview to load **RTF** which we get by invoking a service.

```
[self.messageWebView loadData:[somemessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                             MIMEType:@"text/rtf"
                     textEncodingName:@"utf-8"
                              baseURL:nil];
```

On

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    frame.size.width = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    webViewSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = webViewSize;
    webView.frame = frame;
}
```

This is how we are calculating the height of webview based on this [How to determine the content size of a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview) But the size I get is not accurate. I also tried the other solution as suggested in the other post based on Scrollview, unfortunately even that solution did not work.

Can someone suggest if there is a better approach to calculate the height based on content.