# Resizing UIWebView with sizeThatFits: doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have the following code:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth, 1)];
[webView loadHTMLString:[input objectForKey:@"htmlContent"] baseURL:nil];
CGSize size = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(kWidth, FLT_MAX)];
webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth, size.height);
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(webView.frame));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(size));
```

The idea was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3937599/2339141) answer and as OP mentions before using `sizeThatFits` there is a minimum size chosen i.e. 1. The output of on the screen is as follows:

```
{{0, 0}, {768, 1}}
{768, 1}
```

In other words, the height doesn't get modified and what ever value I will pick instead of 1, it will remain as the height of my view.  What exactly am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because loadHTMLString is async, your sizeThatFits method will be called before the actual html is loaded and rendered.

What I suggest is one, implement UIWebViewDelegate protocol

```
webView.delegate = self;
```

and then

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGSize size = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(kWidth, FLT_MAX)];
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth, size.height);
}
```

NOTE : I don't see anywhere in your code where you are adding your webview as a subview, but I am assuming you are

Comment: +1. Also, if your HTML string contains multiple frames, you might want to count those in `webViewDidStartLoad:`, decrease the count in `webViewDidFinishLoad:`, and update the view when you decrease to `0`.

Comment: The `sizeThatFits` method returns a `CGSize` so in your example nothing would happen.

Comment: You are right. I was just saying where he could then use the method.. but i'll edit with the usage of it