# Implementing UIWebView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm trying to use UIWebView inside UIScrollView, I want to display an webview under an image and make them scrollable.
So I flowed those step :

1. Desactivate the Scroll Property for UIWebView
2. Set the UIScrollView and UIWebView height equals to content size.

And this my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        self.contentReader.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                                       "<head> \n"
                                       "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                                       "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %d;}\n"
                                       "</style> \n"
                                       "</head> \n"
                                       "<body>%@</body> \n"
                                       "</html>", @"JF Flat", 18, self.thePost.content];

        [self.contentReader loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='text-align:right; text-align:justify; direction:rtl'><style type='text/css'>img { max-width: 100%%; width: auto; height: auto; }</style><style type='text/css'>iframe { max-width: 100%%; width: auto; height: auto; }</style>%@<div>",myDescriptionHTML] baseURL:nil];

    }
    -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        // get the html content height
        NSString *output = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height;"];
        NSLog(@"Content Size %@",output);
        // adjust the height of webView
        NSLog(@"WebView Hieght before Update%f", webView.frame.size.height);
        CGRect frame = webView.frame;
        frame.size.height = 1;
        webView.frame = frame;
        CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
        frame.size = fittingSize;
        webView.frame = frame;
        NSLog(@"WebView Hieght After Update%f", webView.frame.size.height);
        [self.scroller setContentSize:webView.bounds.size];
    }
```

And This is the Log message :

> ```
> [5150:203791] WebView Hieght before Update360.000000
> [5150:203791] WebView Hieght After Update5888.000000
> ```

The Problem is that when I scroll down the content is not showed, nothing is showed. check the picture : 
[image]

**Update**
Debug View Hearachy.
[image]

As you can see the WebView height in the view hierarchy hasn't changed. Only the web page has changed the size.

Comment: you should debug the view hierarchy to see if the webView and scrollView frames are adjusted correctly. The log messages seem right.

Comment: Just a thought but have you considered the user experience for this? Because really you're going to end up with a scrollview (UIWebView) inside a scrollview and that can be really annoying sometimes for users when scrolling the wrong view.

Comment: @Popeye I have desabled the webview scrolling property to avoid this confusion. Also I need to display an image with some text and under it HTML text this why I used imageview and uiwebview inside scrollview. Also do have any suggestion or solution to achieve what I need to display please ?

Comment: The screenshots in the update are totally meaningless to me. Did you see a problem?

Comment: @OrtwinGentz I've updated the picture and this ViewHearchi what payed my attention that the UIWebView size is always the same and only the UIWebBrowser have been changed maybe this cause the problem ? (I'm new on IOS development )

Comment: Indeed, that's the issue. Are you using perhaps Auto Layout? Then you can't set the frame manually but have to alter the constant of a height constraint.

Comment: Yeah I'm using autoLayout, and how to alter the constraint of height ?

Comment: @OrtwinGentz Thank's a lot your last comment was very Helpful, So to resume working with auto layout doesn't allow you to change the view size directly you have to change the constraint so I created an IBOutlet for the constraint height then I changed it and it work's fine. Thanks

Comment: @Chlebta Since a web view can already contain images and scroll, have you thought about just using a web view and just modifying the HTML before displaying it? Or alternately, creating a web page for the image and using an `iframe` HTML tag below it to load the web page underneath it? It's all just strings referencing URLs, after all.

Comment: @uliwitness yeah but I didnt used that solution because I'm adding image , label an butons before the scrollview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already solved it in the comments, so let's just put this answer for completeness' sake.

If you're using Auto Layout, make sure to change the size of the WebView by setting constraints such as a height constraint and changing its constant to make the layout change. If you want to animate a specific Auto Layout change, do something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.webViewHeightConstraint.constant = fittingSize.height;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, I m using my phone tomorow I Will Check the animation and give you my feed-back  and also I Will add my functional code on your poste if you don't minde ?

Comment: Sure, feel free to add it.

Comment: Hello, you said that we need to add height constraint. Do we need to add it programmatically or usign storyboard? That code you posted in answer, will it be in webviewDidFinishLoad function?

Comment: what does layoutIfNeeded means. Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: @YestayMuratov when using Auto Layout, `-layoutIfNeeded` kicks off the actual layout change based on the constraint changes. This is needed if changes should be animated. If animation is not needed, UIKit will change the layout in the next runloop iteration automatically, even without `-layoutIfNeeded`.

Comment: My layouts are located right. I have problem calculating height of webView. If there is no image, it calculates right. If I have several images, I need 191px more height. This is constant number that I need. I dont know why I am getting this result

Comment: @YestayMuratov sounds like your problem has nothing to do with the question asked here. I recommend posting a separate question.

Comment: Can you look at my question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732959/calculating-uiwebview-height-with-images-gives-wrong-answer

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a long shot but you might want to try

```
webView.scrollView.contentSize = fittingSize;
```

or

```
webView.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);
```

Because scrolling was turned off the content size or frame may not be changing after loading the html. Like I said a long shot but might work.

Comment: I've tried this but always getting same issue the WebView content not proprly showen.