# calculating UIWebView height with images gives wrong answer

Tags: swift, uiwebview, height

I found how to calculate dynamic uiwebview height according to its content. My code is :

```
  println("webViweDidFinish started")

    var frame:CGRect = myWebView.frame

    frame.size.height = 1

    var fittingSize :CGSize = myWebView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)

    frame.size = fittingSize

    myWebView.frame = frame


    var contentsizeHeight = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height

    var yCoordinateOfWebView = myWebView.frame.origin.y


    var contentHeight: CGFloat = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;

    myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, yCoordinateOfWebView + contentsizeHeight + labelAuthorOfArticle.frame.height) //

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.heightConstraints.constant = fittingSize.height

        self.myWebView.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.myScrollContentView.layoutIfNeeded()

    })



    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

If I use this approach:

```
        var height:NSString! = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.height;")

    var heightInFloat = height.floatValue
```

How to convert height to CGFloat? I can only convert it to float as you see.

The problem is that when webview has too many images the height is calculated wrong. Oppositely when there is no image height is calculated right. When I reload the function, the second time it calculates right (with images). Here is content of string that I am loading:

```
 class func formatContentText(inout text: NSString)-> NSString{

    text = text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("src=\"", withString: "src=\"http://dixinews.kz")
    var deviceWidth = "300"
    text = "<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"user-scalable=no, width=" + deviceWidth + " , maximum-scale=1.0\"><style>img{max-width:100%%;height:auto !important;width:auto !important;};</style></head><body>" + text + "</body></html>"

    return text
}
```

Comment: You're mixing several concepts. First, you set the frame and update the constraints. Either you use Auto Layout, then you have to change a height constraint constant, or you don't, then you don't need to update constraints. Second, you're determining the content height using two different strategies (using the sizeThatFits trick and using JS) and overwrite the first with the second. I recommend to clean up the code first.

Comment: Can you look again, I cleared the code

Answer (score 0):

I used approach with javascript. Here is my code:

```
  func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {





    var frame:CGRect = myWebView.frame



    // javascript
    var height:NSString! = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.height;")

    var heightInFloat = height.floatValue // convert to float

    var heightINCGFloat = CGFloat(heightInFloat) convert to cgfloat

    frame.size.height = heightINCGFloat //set heigh

    myWebView.frame = frame // set frame

    myWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height = myWebView.frame.height

    var contentsizeHeight = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height

    var yCoordinateOfWebView = myWebView.frame.origin.y

    myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, yCoordinateOfWebView + contentsizeHeight + labelAuthorOfArticle.frame.height) //

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.heightConstraints.constant = heightINCGFloat

        self.myWebView.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.myScrollContentView.layoutIfNeeded()

    })

    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()


}
```

Comment: document.height does not exist

Comment: maybe after some updates it is deprecated, try to google what u can use instead.