# iOS API - sizeThatFits: does not work

Tags: ios

UPDATE:

Sorry I didn't describe it enough and incorrectly before.

I did some code like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
CGSize size = [view sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
```

But when I observe `size`, it got nothing: `{0, 0}`.

Do I use it wrong?

Even I passed in an initial frame to my view, the size still returned nothing.

I searched some posts and someone said `UILabel` may also gets affected.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview . It the best possible way to calculate the correct size of webview.

Answer (score 3):

Your view does't contain any content and it does't have any intristic content size, so it will have zero size.

Try these and you will see that it works:

```
UILabel *label [UILabel new];
label.text = @"test test test test";
CGSize size = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(20, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```

Comment: @xxxy2j actually I was reading someone's source code and found some error, when I debugged it I found his code here had some abnormality as I described on the post.

Answer (score 1):

As a @Konstantin said:

> Your view does't contain any content and it does't have any inartistic
>   content size

So try to use this code

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
CGSize size = view.size;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the description of `sizeThatFits`, it states,

> Asks the view to calculate and return the size that best fits the
>   specified size. A new size that fits the receiver’s subviews.

So, your view should have some subview or content otherwise it will return `0,0`.