# how to get correct hight when we have some content on UIWebView in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have disqusView(link) in UIWebView, I want to scroll webView as the size of disqusView, I don't want default scroll of webView

here is my code, in these I'm getting more height then actual height of webView content size.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

 let cgfloat = web_discus.scrollView.contentSize.height as CGFloat
}
```

or

```
web_discus.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.hight")! as String
```

but both give more height then actual that`s why it show more blank space while scrolling down..

I also tried this one :

```
web_discus.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.offsetHeight")! as String
```

Is there any way to get perfect hight for webView content ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want the `contentSize` of the `webView`? If that is the case, then this other StackOverflow question should point you in the right direction [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview)

Essentially you'd do `webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, I think you should use [window.pageYOffset](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_pagexoffset.asp):

```
if let myPostion = web_discus.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.pageYOffset"), let myPostionCGFloat = NumberFormatter().number(from: myPostion) {
        web_discus.scrollView.contentSize.height = CGFloat(myPostionCGFloat)
    }
}
```