# Scroll to anchor in webView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, uiwebview

We would like to open a WebView with a specific location opened in the view.
Therefore we would like to scroll to an anchor OR jump to it before it is shown.

We tried to execute a javascript inside of the `viewWillAppear`, but it does not work. If we execute it in the `viewDidAppear` we have a jump to the anchor which is not a valid solution.

WebContentView (Simple Storyboard with a `UIView` containing a single WebView):

```
class WebContentViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    var fileName: String?
    var screenName: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let url = URLRequest(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "html")!)
        webView.loadRequest(url);
        webView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        guard let screenName = screenName else {
            return
        }

        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.location.href = '#2-einsatz-von-google-analytics';")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.location.href = '#2-einsatz-von-google-analytics';") //creates a jump instead of a scrole
    }
}
```

Tried solutions and known questions:

- Using `scrollTo(hash) {location.hash = "#" + hash;}; scrollTo("anchor");` [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor using jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript)
- [Is it possible to send a hash tag to a file url in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127849/is-it-possible-to-send-a-hash-tag-to-a-file-url-in-uiwebview)

How can we accomplish a "smooth" scroll to the anchor or a jump before it is visible?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993770/how-to-get-correct-hight-when-we-have-some-content-on-uiwebview-in-swift-ios/39994174#39994174) useful for your case?

Answer (score 0):

In decidePolicyFor delegate method of WkWebView, you can do this in Swift 5 (with dispatch on main thread and little delay to make it work every time):

```
 ...
 if url.scheme == "about" && url.absoluteString.starts(with: "about:blank%23")  { // %23 = #
      let anchor = url.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "about:blank%23", with: "")
      let javascript = "document.getElementById('\(anchor)').offsetTop"
      webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript) { [weak self] (result, error) in
           if let offset = result as? CGFloat {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.1) {
                     webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: offset), animated: true)
                }
           }
      }
      decisionHandler(.allow)
 }
 ...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are familiar with [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview), you should know that you can use [setContentOffset](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619400-setcontentoffset) method. By default, the [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scrollView) has a scrollView property:

> var scrollView: UIScrollView The scroll view associated with the web
>   view.

So, what you can do -for example- is:

```
webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100), animated: true)
```

**Also**, I think you should use it after the webView finished loading, you can achieve this by implementing [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate) - [webViewDidFinishLoad](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617969-webviewdidfinishload):

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100), animated: true)
}
```

Hope this helped.