# Get the height of a website requested with UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I request a Website with this code

```
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj)

            print (myWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height) //1
            print (myWebView.frame.size.height)   //2
```

The code always return 1000.0 when the real size of the website is much more than that. Is there a way to get the real size ? I want to show the hole content of a WebView without the need of scrolling within the WebView.

Comment: Does your website developed with `Bootstrap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method, this answer was originally founded here [How to determine the content size of a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview)

In your `viewDidLoad` method do something like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.webView.loadHTMLString(component.html, baseURL: nil)
    self.webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    self.webView.scrollView.bounces = false
    self.webView.delegate = self
    self.delegate = delegate
}

public func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
    var frame = webView.frame
    frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame = frame

    let fittingSize = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
    frame.size = fittingSize
    webView.frame = frame
    webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

    self.delegate?.heightHasChanged(indexPath:self.indexPath, newHeight: frame.height)
    self.loadingView.isHidden = true
    self.loadingActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

I hope this helps you, best regards